# Invalid linkification in comments

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks

I just tried to link to this page in a comment:

http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Treachery,_Faith_and_the_Great_River_%28episode%29

Unfortunately, the shorthand used in comments sometimes breaks on the comma, and tries to italicize the word "Faith".

[Broken example here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53756/how-did-nog-beat-the-kobayashi-maru#comment104050_53756), <strike>with the additional note that it doesn't always break and I don't know why.  It worked correctly when I tried to create an example on this question.</strike>

Edit now that I look again - I *did* try to italicize the word "something" at the end of the comment, outside the link.  It caught that, so the last underscore is missing.  It just didn't actually italicize, presumably because the tag order <a><i></a></i> is invalid.

Short format [does not break here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Treachery,_Faith_and_the_Great_River_%28episode%29) under the *same* conditions.

---

**Per Keen's request:**

Broken comment:

```
[link](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Treachery,_Faith_and_the_Great_River_%28episode%29) text _this should be italic_
```

[image: Broken comment]

---

A working comment, which does not have a comma in the link, but does use italics after the link:

```
[No-comma test](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_commanders) some text _should be italic_
```

[image: No-comma comment]

---

Same format as the broken comment working correctly in the question text:

```
Short format [does not break here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Treachery,_Faith_and_the_Great_River_%28episode%29) under the _same_ conditions.
```

[image: Working in question]

Comment: [Test example](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Treachery,_Faith_and_the_Great_River_%28episode%29) (that for some reason, works..)

Comment: [link](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Treachery,_Faith_and_the_Great_River_(episode)) text _this should be italic_

Comment: [No-comma test](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_commanders) some text _should be italic_

Comment: You should include in the question the full markdown code each of the above comments is using, along with screenshots of the result comment.

Comment: [test](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Treachery%2C_Faith_and_the_Great_River_%28episode%29) - yes, using "%2C" instead of a comma works.

Comment: @Keen Added a couple